# Use of Future for concurrent search and result return

Tags: scala

I'm creating a Service that runs through a list of words and for each word it checks if there's a related action(execution) in the database.

I'm trying to do this concurrently using Futures and I'm not sure if I'm using the best way.

```

```
class CommandDiscoveryService (commandsDAO: CommandsDAO, text: String) {

  val words = text.split("\\s+")

  var results = new ListBuffer[Option[Execution]]()

  // Temporarily handle with concurrent searchs on the database
  // TODO Load all commands to memory and check the list ?? memcache or some other cache service
  if (words.size <= 6) {
    Logger.debug("Searching for executions with text " + text )
    findExecution()
  }

  def findExecution() = {
    val lb = new ListBuffer[Future[Seq[Execution]]]()
    for (word <- words) {
      lb += commandsDAO.findExecutionByName(word)
    }

    lb.foreach(Await.result(_, 1 seconds))

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // FIXME LATER
    val res = lb.map {
      ftr => ftr.map{
        res => {
          if (res.size > 0 ) {
            Logger.debug("RES SIZE:" + res.size)
            res.map{ ex => results += Some(ex) }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def getExecution(): Option[Execution] = {
    if (results.size > 1 ) {
      Logger.debug("ERROR_TOMANYEXECS: Found more than one execution " + results.head)
      results.foreach{
        execs => Logger.debug("ERROR_TOMANYEXECS: " + execs)
      }

      None
    } else {
      if (results.size == 0 ) {
        Logger.debug("NOTHING FOUND IN RES")
        None
      } else {
        Logger.debug("FOUND RES " + results.head)
        results.head
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```

When I call getExecution I need to already have obtained the value of the search done. I'm not sure if doing a lock on this results variable will be a solution has to the Await on the Future[Seq[Execution]] Is already not recomended.

PS: I'm using playframework 2.6.x and Slick for this to run on.

Comment: No. Await.result is blocking and hence it is not good

Comment: But I need to wait on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `results` `ListBuffer` is only populated with `Some[Execution]`, never with a `None`, so there's no point in using an `Option` there. I recommend working with immutable collections and redefining your `findExecution` method to return a `Future[List[Execution]]`:

```
val words = text.split("\\s+").toList

def findExecution: Future[List[Execution]] = {
  val executions = words.map(commandsDAO.findExecutionByName(_)) // List[Future[Seq[Execution]]]
  val filtered = executions.map(_.filter(_.nonEmpty)) // List[Future[Seq[Execution]]
  val flattened = Future.sequence(filtered).map(_.flatten) // Future[List[Execution]]
  flattened
}
```

`findExecution` now returns a single `Future` of all the `Execution`s of all the words or names, except for the words that do not have any `Execution`s.

> When I call getExecution I need to already have obtained the value of the search done

A better approach would be to make `getExecution` return a `Future` as well:

```
def getExecution: Future[Option[Exception]] = {
  val executions = findExecution // Future[List[Execution]]
  executions.map { e =>
    if (e.size > 1) {
      // ...
      None
    } else if (e.isEmpty) {
      // ...
      None
    } else { // e.size is one
      // ...
      Some(e.head)
    }
  }
}
```

The above approach avoids the blocking `Await` call and fits into the asynchronous Play and Slick APIs.

Comment: I had to change the sequence(filtered) to sequence(filtered.toList) for it to compile, other then that seems to work.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Interrupted during connection acquisition ... I'm getting this error, can I assume the Future isn't waiting for completion?